# Infinite loop while reversing a linked list in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

So I have this code

```
class Node():
  def __init__(self, data): 
    self.data = data 
    self.next = None
   

class LinkedList():
  def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.length = 0

  def prepend(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    new_node.next = self.head
    self.head = new_node
    self.length += 1

  def print_list(self):
    if self.head == None:
      print('Empty')
    else:
      currentNode = self.head
      while currentNode != None:
        print(currentNode.data, end = ' ')
        currentNode = currentNode.next

  def reverse(self):
    first = self.head
    second = first.next
    while second:
        temp = second.next
        second.next = first
        first = second
        second = temp
```

I prepend and then have a list of [8,7,11,6,5,10].
When I try to use the reverse function and try to print out I get infinite loop of 8 and 7. I'm not sure why. I thought the first already points to the self.head so that when it gets changed, the self.head gets changed as well. But its not the case. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: What is the `first = second` part intended to do? And didn't you intend to do something with `first.next`?

Comment: The first = second part is intended to reassign the object. Like for exp, when first = 8,7,11,6,5,10 then second.next would be: 8, 7,11,6,5,10 then first will be reassigned to be  7,8,7,11,6,5,10. It goes on until all the data property of the class are in the reverse position

Comment: Try drawing a diagram on paper to keep track of the process. Make sure you [understand how names work in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel. Now I figure that second node is pointing towards the first node which creates infinite loop of self.head, which could be fixed by assigning self.head = first after the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `reverse` method is focussing on only the first two elements, and setting up cyclic references between them.

Here's the modified `reverse()` method, that works. (Note that the `reverse()` method contains an enclosed helper function called `rev_()`, which recurses through the linked list):

```
def reverse (self):          #------------MODIFIED--------------
    def rev_ (head):
        rest = head.next
        if rest is None:
            return head
        else:
            reversed_rest = rev_(rest)
            rest.next = head
            head.next = None
            return reversed_rest
        if self.head is not None:
            self.head = rev_(self.head)
```

**Testing it out:**

```
my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.print_list()
print()
my_list.reverse()
my_list.print_list()
print()
my_list.prepend(21)
my_list.print_list()
print()
my_list.reverse()
my_list.print_list()
print()
my_list.prepend(22)
my_list.prepend(23)
my_list.print_list()
print()
my_list.reverse()
my_list.print_list()
```

**Output:**

```
Empty

Empty

21 
21 
23 22 21 
21 22 23
```